# What means "eHealth intervention"

Tags: meaning, phrase-meaning, phrase-usage, writing

I am aware what *eHealth* is, however I cannot figure out, what "eHealth intervention" exactly means.

Specifically, can I call an app that is healthcare related an eHealth intervention?

Comment: What does *eHealth* mean? What does ***health*** *intervention* mean? If you know the latter, just substitute the former word into the phrase.

Comment: @JasonBassford I am not certain what it means.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The term "health intervention" is medical jargon (medical professionals *do* love their jargon) that simply refers to a medical treatment to address a specific condition. Making it "*e*Health intervention" implies some type of virtual visit to a doctor or other medical professional who then prescribes a treatment.

Comment: So an app that contains some kind of functionality you described could be called "eHealth intervention"? --> "This app is an eHealth intervention."

Comment: Actually, no. The app would be the means by which a person could receive an eHealth intervention. If you wanted, you could call the name of the app "eHealth Intervention."